# Laravel Patch AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a modal that updates information on countries.

```
 // Partial code of the modal
<div id="EditModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;  </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit <label id="EntityType"></label></h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    @yield('EditModalBody')
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer" style="text-align: center">
                {{ Form::submit('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-success', 'id' => 'editBtn']) }}
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                {!! Form::close() !!}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to implement this with AJAX, so that if there are any errors, the modal does not close and the error messaged appear under each input field.

This is my JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#EditModal").submit(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var selector = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'PATCH',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: selector.attr("action"),
        data: selector.serialize(),

        success: function (data) {
            if (data.success) {
                alert('go go go');
            } else {
                // for debugging
                alert('data');

            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    });
});
```

I am getting "405 Method not allowed" error, although I declared my controller as a "ressource" like this:

```
Route::resource('country', 'CountryController',
            ['except' => ['show']]);
```

If I do `php artisan route:list` I can see that the PATCH route is declared.

Any ideas?

EDIT 1:

This is (part of) my controller:

```
public function update($id, Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $this->getRules(), $this->getMesssages());

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            $json = new stdClass();
            $json->success = false;
            $json->errors = $Validator->errors();
        }
        else {
            $json = new stdClass();
            $json->success = true;
        }

        return Response::json($json);
```

EDIT 2:

So I added this `<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{{ csrf_token() }}}"/>` in my modal and I no longer get the 405 error. I still have a problem that I always get the "error" part of my JS (only that now I get status 0)

Comment: Can you tell how the selector.attr("action") looks like.

Comment: It should be looks like /country/idOrSomething

Comment: correct. it is `country/id`

Comment: This is how I declare my form action

`<script>
 $(function () {
  $('#EditModal').on("show.bs.modal", function (e) {
   // Some other code...
   document.editEntity.action = "{{ url('country') }}" + '/' + $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
  });
 });
</script>`

Answer (score 1):

`type: 'PATCH'` does not exists on HTTP methods thus will not be recognized by Laravel.
Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: selector.attr("action"),
    data: {
        '_method': 'PATCH',
        'data': selector.serialize(),
    },
```

You have to submit the method `PATCH` as `_method` Post data.

**Edit**
Your controller function looks wrong. The correct order would be

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
```

instead of

```
public function update($id, Request $request)
```

---

OT: I already submitted an addition for the Laravel documentation that gives you a hint about this problem but it was rejected with no comment.

Comment: Are you sure that you use the correct route / URL? A `post` request with the post data `_method=PATCH` should be accepted by an `update` route. - 
See https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers

Comment: If I do `dd($request);` in the controller, I can see that the method is correctly executing as PATCH. I'm confused...

Comment: So you have the CountryController and the update() function, correct? How or where do you do the `dd()`? Because normally the 405 error is thrown by the middleware and not the controller itself.

Comment: So I added this `<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{{ csrf_token() }}}"/>` in my modal and I no longer get the 405 error.
I still have a problem that I always get the "error" part of my JS (only that now I get status 0)

Comment: I tried it but had no influence. This method works fine with no-ajax calls. When doing dd() on the request, I can see al the data (name, id, etc.) of the form